# How do I pass a cin'd c style string to a function?

Tags: c++

I can assign a c-style string to a variable and pass it to a function, and I can cin/cout a c-style string, but I can't cin a c-style string and *then* pass it to a function. How do I do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class SzString // edit 2: changed to Upper Camel for class name (Thanks Rabbiya Shahid)
{
    int m_length;
    char* m_szString;

public:
    void SetString(char* szString) // b) line on which program crashes after call from 'line a'
    {
        m_szString = szString;
        m_length = strlen(szString);
    }

    char* GetString()
    {
        return m_szString;
    }

};

SzString aString;

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    char* szString; // line x (referenced following 'EDIT:')
    cin >> szString;
    aString.SetString(szString);  // line a

    cout << endl << aString.GetString();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I fixed it two ways. First, I changed to using std::string as I was advised, then I went back to c-style Strings and fixed it a second way by changing line x: `char* szString` to `char* szString = new char` (based on being reminded that `char* szString` didn't allocate space).

Edit 3: (Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ)

Added the following to c-style string version of code after 'line a' to prevent memory leak:

```
szString = 0;
delete[] szString;
```

Comment: Your life is going to be 100x better if you just use `std::string`.

Comment: Uh oh. You can't just extract into a `char*` like that without actually allocating the space for the `char`s.

Comment: szString is a type, since it is a class, you are writing char* before that in the function definition.

Comment: As for your edit: You might have a memory leak now, take care!

Comment: Parse a `std::string` via `cin` and `SetString` via `std::string::c_str`. But you'll have to copy the string first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `main` function you have the definition

```
char* szString;
```

That tells the compiler that `szString` is a pointer to characters. But you don't make that pointer *actually point* to anything.

So when you use it to get input, the input operation will write the input to some unknown location. This is *undefined behavior*, and will cause your program to behave unexpectedly, including crashing.

Either you have to make the pointer point to some valid location. Or even better, don't use pointers for strings, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 3):

```
char* szString;
cin >> szString;
```

This code doesn't do what you might think it does! To input a string from `cin` use:

```
std::string s;
cin >> s;
```

Change further occurences of `char*` to `std::string`, `std::string&` accordingly.